# Uso e significato di "appeso" / "appendere" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

Nel libro *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> E ricominciò, già rinfrancato, col tono di prima: Debiti mai **appesi** in vita sua, al massimo qualche conticino d’albergo, qualche pranzo al ristorante, qualche whisky. Ma in cambio, quelli che chiudevano un occhio si vedevano arrivare clienti che nemmeno se li sognavano. Tre o quattro di loro e il posto diventava chic, tutti ci correvano.

E un po' più avanti nel libro si trova:

> «Questa è la zona dove abito io. Ho segnato in rosso tutte le strade dove ho **appeso** debiti, qua col tabaccaio, là col salumiere, là con un portiere. Circolare diventa sempre più difficile, tutte le strade d’uscita sono sbarrate. Vedi, è rimasto libero solo questo passaggio» e me lo mostrava sulla pianta.

Ho cercato alle voci "appendere" e "appeso" di parecchi dizionari, inclusi il [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appendere) e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000569.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000571.jpg)]), ma non sono riuscita a trovare nessuna accezione che abbia senso nel contesto di questi due brani.

La mia domanda è: "appendere debiti" significherebbe "contrarre debiti"? Si tratta di un uso regionale del verbo "appendere"? Di qualche sorta di gergo o "slang"?

Comment: È un'espressione che non avevo mai sentito ma mi sembra evidente che si riferisca a debiti che non sono stati ancora saldati. Normalmente, ho sempre sentito l'espressione debiti _pendenti_, per indicarli; immagino che "appesi", che è anche molto vicino semanticamente, venga usato allo stesso modo.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo me possiamo applicare la definizione del Treccani:

> Part. pass. appéso anche come agg., attaccato, sospeso:

quindi il debito "appeso" è da interpretarsi come *"sospeso"* in senso figurato, ovvero "in sospeso", non ancora saldato.

Comment: Quindi, il significato sarebbe quello dell'[accezione 2.c di "sospeso"](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sospeso)? Tuttavia, mi sembra di capire che questo "sospeso" appartiene al registro burocratico o a un linguaggio tecnico dell'ambito del commercio. E poi, si potrebbe dire "debiti mai *sospesi* in vita sua, al massimo qualche conticino d’albergo, qualche..." o "le strade dove ho *sospeso* debiti, qua col tabaccaio, là col salumiere, là..."?

Comment: L'espressione corretta sarebbe secondo me in questo caso "in sospeso" (avere un conto /debito in sospeso).

Comment: Cioè, @Riccardo, potrei dire "debiti mai *in sospeso* in vita sua, al massimo qualche conticino d’albergo, qualche..." o "le strade dove ho *in sospeso* debiti, qua col tabaccaio, là col salumiere, là..."?

Comment: @Charo la prima non mi suona molto naturale, la seconda sì. Forse questione di gusti.

Comment: Concordo con il significato di "lasciato in sospeso". Comunque, suona dialettale, e/o desueto.